# Hi, is this a right way to pass on a number variable to a function in a template literal?

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, flask

```
        function makeCard(title, content, memo_num) {
            let temp_html = `<div class="card" id="card number${memo_num}">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 id="memo_title" class="card-title">${title}</h3>
                                <h4 id="memo_content" class="card-text">${content}</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick="updateArticle(${memo_num})">수정</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" onclick="deleteArticle(${memo_num})">삭제</button>
                                </div>
                             </div>`;

            $("#cards-box").append(temp_html);
        }
```

So my code is this, and I'm creating cards using data from a database.

About the variable memo_num, it is given to makeCard() as a number variable.
So is this the right way to hand on the variable to the function "updateArticle()" in this template literal?

In past experience when I put ' ' around the ${ } it worked(for a string variable, though)

Currently the button is not performing what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed a Flask application, then you would follow the [Jinja2 templating guidelines](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/). Basically, after you use the `render template` function, you define your variables in the arguments, then call them in your html code using double curly braces, so you would say `{{title}}`